# Connection refused laravel SQL: select count(*) as aggregate

Tags: laravel-5

I change the default auth in laravel and replace the email to username.
Then I login using username and s

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection
>   refused (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `users` where `email`
>   = dulaj@gmail.com)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

restart the server and check again..

Comment: when you can  answer to something , try to give good description